# Is it okay to mix HDD models of the same size and manufacturer in a home server RAID 1 array?

Tags: home-server, raid-1

I've got a WD Caviar Green drive I'd like to put in a hardware RAID 1 array for a home server (for storing music, photos, etc). Problem is, the specific model I have isn't shipping any more. Will I be okay pairing it with a newer model, specifically if the newer version has a larger cache (64MB compared to 32MB)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - this might even be a good idea - [least according to this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/317355/should-you-still-s), since you'd have different failure rates between the disks. Your system is probably *not* aware of the larger cache at raid level, and the system should work at least as well as if you had two 32 mb cached disks.